# know the domain of the action called in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dns

I have 2 domain:
domain1.com
and
domain2.com

how can i know what is the domain that the user used to call a action?

like

domain1.com/controller/action

i want get domain1.com from the action

is possible?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [`host`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Request.html#M000712) method. If you require the port as well, use `host_with_port`.

Answer (score 1):

this should be possible by looking at the request object, see chapter 9.1 in the [Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_controller_overview.html#the-request-object).

```
domain(n=2)     The hostname’s first n segments, starting from the right (the TLD).
```

Hope this helps.